# Inno Setup Using Variable in [icon] and [Registry]

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am new to Inno Setup.

I have defined a few global variables in the [code] section.
I want to make use of it in [icons], [Files], and [Registry]

My start menu would depend on a few conditions. To simplify, I will derive where the shortcuts will be created and store the full path in the variable.

Assuming I have set the following Path in the code section.

```
CustomStartMenu:='C:\Users\Rajendra\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs';
```

I would like Inno Installer to create all the shortcuts based on the variable CustomStartMenu

```
[Icons]
Name: "{#CustomStartMenuPath}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\myApp.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; IconFilename: "{app}\myapp.ico"; IconIndex: 0
```

Another Example
variable DotPaintAppPath

```
[Files]
Source: "c:\myplugin.exe"; DestDir: "{#DotPaintAppPath}\Effects\MyApp"; DestName: "MyApp.exe"; Flags: ignoreversion replacesameversion restartreplace;
Source: "c:\myapp1.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "myapp1.exe"; Flags: ignoreversion replacesameversion restartreplace;
Source: "c:\myapp2.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "myapp2.exe"; Flags: ignoreversion replacesameversion restartreplace;
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. I will try and I will update here. I am not hardcoding it, that was just for an example. I will get the StartMenu of the Windows Username's Start Menu Folder. Windows Username will be specified during the installation. During the installation, I will capture Windows username [Text Box], validate the same, and then build the path where the files should be copied.

Answer (score 0):

You should use {code:...} constant.

Take icons for

```
[Icons]
Name: "{code:GetMyPath}\MyApp"; Filename: "{app}\myApp.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; IconFilename: "{app}\myapp.ico"; IconIndex: 0

[code]
function GetMyPath(Param: String): string;
begin
  Result := CustomStartMenu;
end;
```